# Trying to Vagrant up using Vmware Fusion - Getting file not found error

Tags: vagrant, vmware-fusion

Getting this error:

```
The executable '/Users/nick/vs/mmvagrant/Contents/Library/vmware-vmx' Vagrant is trying to run was not
found in the PATH variable. This is an error. Please verify
this software is installed and on the path.
```

(im vagrant upping in my ~/vs/mmvagrant folder)

Purchased, installed and properly licensed vmware-fusion

Selecting this in the puphpet as a Local option, and i get the above failure message. When I run with VirtualBox, its fine.

Where can I find this contents/library reference, or what can I add to my path?

(Apple OS/X)

Comment: Have you tried `vagrant up --provision --provider=vmware_fusion`?  Also, have you moved or renamed (`mv`) your PuPHPet directory from wherever it was on your system since the last time your box was provisioned?

Comment: Thank you for suggestion - Unfortunately that did not help, it still gives the same error. No i have not moved any puphpet files around from existing, these are a new install.

Comment: Okay two things I'd like to know:  (1) What happens when you type this command in terminal:  `which vmware-vmx`?  And... (2) What happens when you type this command in terminal:  `file /Users/nick/vs/mmvagrant/Contents/Library/vmware-vmx`?

Comment: Nothing on `which vmware-vmx` and no file found. Contents folder does not exist. I am tryint to `vagrant up` in a directory. All I have is a New vagrant file from `vagrant init hashicorp/precise64` - I think this should really be looking in vagrants root directory for /Contents/Library right?

Comment: PuPHPet shouldn't really be using `hashicorp/precise64` - it should be using CentOS, Debian or Ubuntu.  But to answer your question, the `which` command searches your path, in this case, for `vmware-vmx`.  The fact that the `which` command is failing to find it explains the error you've described and answers the question - but doesn't solve your problem.  Let's take a look at the Vagrant vs. PuPHPet thing, though?

Comment: Sorry - I had ran a new vagrant init, for the sake of eliminating puphpet. Puphpet works without vagrant vmware; anything (even CLI) using vagrant vmware-vmx fusion plugin is failing.

Comment: I have this feeling that even though the plugin is sold from vagrant up, it needs something else to make it work. Their docs are (Imo) garbage and void of useful support for their specific plugin. Any ideas on how to add their fusion plugin to my path?

Comment: Hand-coding the `Vagrantfile` is **NOT** for the faint at heart.  I'd go right back to PuPHPet if I were you!  But for now, let's find out where _vmware-vmx_ went.  From your terminal, type:  `find / -name vmware-vmx 2> /dev/null`.  This searches for the file starting at the root (`/`) of your filesystem and dumps all the _"Permission denied"_ errors to `/dev/null` (basically, they won't then be shown).  Let me know what that turns up.

Comment: Ha - vmware missing. Went to download latest, Vmware official site down. Guessing that will solve the issue (latest)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In PuPHPet, one must choose a "provider" which exists on your system:

[image]

PuPHPet will create a `Vagrantfile` that makes certain assumptions based on your choice of provider.  In your case, you have chosen **VMWare Fusion**, which the question assumes is installed but in fact is not.  This causes this error:

> The executable `vmware-vmx` Vagrant is trying to run was not found in the PATH variable.

Reinstall VMWare Fusion, then make sure the VMWare Fusion Plugin is installed (with the `vagrant plugin list` command).  Finally, with all those pieces in place, try `vagrant up` again.